# Snowboy with statically linked libraries

Tags: python, linux, makefile, swig, atlas

I'm trying to make the Snowboy Python library without dynamically linking to the Atlas libraries on a Linux ARM32 platform. The Makefile has this comment:

```
SWIGFLAGS := -shared
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
# Make sure you have Atlas installed. You can statically link Atlas if you
# would like to be able to move the library to a machine without Atlas.
LDLIBS := -lm -ldl -lf77blas -lcblas -llapack_atlas -latlas
```

I tried placing "-Bstatic" before the Atlas links, but it didn't seem to have any effect and is still linking dynamically. I also tried changing the SWIGFLAGS to -static, but that resulted in many errors about the glibc standard library not being included.

https://github.com/Kitt-AI/snowboy/blob/master/swig/Python/Makefile

Can someone clue me in to the proper way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Use `-l:liblapack_atlas.a` to link Atlas statically.